# Error in retrieving entries according to date in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created the following database..

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("create table ITEMS(ROW_ID integer primary key autoincrement,ITEM_DESCRIPTION text,ITEM_AMOUNT integer," +
            "time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE);");
}
```

Here time column in the table enters the date on which entry was created.
Now I want to retrieve only those entries to be retrieved which are entered today.
For this I am using the following function.

```
public void getToday(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    SimpleDateFormat f=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date=new Date();
    String x = f.format(date);
    Log.d("DAte string",x);
    Cursor cx=db.rawQuery("Select * from items where time="+ x ,null);
    Log.d("Count",String.valueOf(cx.getCount()));
   for(cx.moveToFirst();!cx.isAfterLast();cx.moveToNext()){

Log.d(".......",cx.getString(cx.getColumnIndex("ITEM_DESCRIPTION")));

    }
     db.close();
}
```

But the count is 0.The cursor is not retrieving any entries.
I have also checked the date format in database. It is the same that I have formatted my date to.
Still I am getting no entries.
Please tell me where I am committing mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor cx=db.rawQuery("Select * from items where time='"+ x+"'" ,null);    

 Log.d("Count",(cx.getCount()));

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
    Log.d(".......",cx.getString(cx.getColumnIndex("ITEM_DESCRIPTION")));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

plese apply this code..and i hope you have already enter data into database.right?
otherwise cursor count retruns 0.

Comment: Ya..I have data in my database and the problem is not in the loop. Coz the count is already zero before executing the loop.The problem lies somewhere in the query.

Comment: Cursor cx=db.rawQuery("Select * from items where time='"+ x+"'" ,null);

try this one.

Comment: You are putting x inside quotes??

Comment: Can you please explain...what did that mean??

Comment: "x" is string and sting must be pass in ' ' (single quote).always...
numbers field not necessary ' '(single quote)..
are you understand?what i am saying?